# Add the same key to both the Tables

Tags: mysql

I am new to mySQL. Not familiar with foreign key

I have 2 Tables : sendm and recievem. The following query inserts data into sendm. It does have id as primary key with autoincrement

```
INSERT INTO `sendm`(`sendname`, `recievename`, `subject`, `body`, `mdate`, `mtime`) VALUES ('$sendname','$recievename','$subject','$body','$mate','$mtime')
```

What i want to have is to insert the same id to the recievem table simultaneously..
Thus having the same id in both tables for the same message.

```
INSERT INTO `recievem`(`sendname`, `recievename`, `subject`, `body`) VALUES ('$sendname','$recievename','$subject','$body')
```

How am i supposed to do that? Please help

Given below is the PHP code which needs to be altered

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sendm`(`sendname`, `recievename`, `subject`, `body`, `mdate`, `mtime`) VALUES ('$sendname','$recievename','$subject','$body','$msgdate','$msgtime')");
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `recievem`(`sendname`, `recievename`, `subject`, `body`) VALUES ('$sendname','$recievename','$subject','$body')");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited according to new specifications:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sendm`(`sendname`, `recievename`, `subject`, `body`, `mdate`, `mtime`) VALUES ('$sendname','$recievename','$subject','$body','$msgdate','$msgtime')");
$new_id = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `recievem`(`YOUR_FIELD_ID`, `sendname`, `recievename`, `subject`, `body`) VALUES ($new_id,'$sendname','$recievename','$subject','$body')");
```

Just need to change `YOUR_FIELD_ID` with the name of the id field of the table `recievem`

**IMPORTANT**:

***Mysql extension are deprecated and will be no longer supported in next PHP versions. Take a look to Mysqli or PDO***

Comment: Yes I am using PHP.. Let me edit the Question and insert it along with the PHP Code

Comment: Also make sure there are no triggers or that last id will be wrong or put all that in a transaction.

Comment: Ok fine let me try.. :-)

Should the Id on recievem be Primary? or just leave it as it is

Comment: Yeah that fixed it.. Thanks very much...

And about the PHP Info you gave - So by next 1 or 2 year these codes won't work??

Comment: In next versions, if one day you want to upgrade your php version to something greater thn 5.6 then you will need to change ALL your **mysql_*** functions, so it's better, if you are developing something new to use **mysqli_*** functions at least (the syntax is similar)